# Determine a winner based on a single random value and an array of probabilities using java streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an array of probability values that add up to `1.0`. I want to determine one winner element based on a random number between 0 and 1:

```
double probabilities[] = {.2, .75, .05};

double randomValue = new Random().nextDouble();
int winner = -1;
Iterator<Double> iterator = Arrays.stream(probabilities).iterator();
double probability = 0;
do {
    winner++;
    probability += iterator.next();
} while (probability < randomValue);
```

I do want to break when the winner is known. How would I do this using streams?

Comment: From the example, `probabilities` is not sorted, so that do/while appears to have a bug.  [This](https://www.baeldung.com/java-stream-indices) could be used as a starting point to use only streams (add a filter), but unless this is an academic exercise a basic loop would probably be easier to read.

Comment: The loop does already break when the winner is known. And the code is already using the Stream API. So all your formal requirements are fulfilled. But a more efficient solution would be `int winner = -1; for(double probability = 0; winner < probabilities.length && probability < randomValue; probability += probabilities[++winner]) {}`

Comment: I was aiming for something like reduce, but with a break condition. I tried `takeWhile`, but everything I came up with was ugly or overly complicated. I often find streams more concise (yes, sometimes sacrificing readability). I can live with the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Streams are not always the best answer but if your probability array contains increasing sums you can do it like this.

```
double probabilities[] = {.2, .95, 1.0}; // increasing
double winningProb = Arrays.stream(probabilities)
    .filter(p -> p >= randomValue).findFirst().getAsDouble();
 
System.out.println(winningProb); // answer matches your other method.
```

You can also convert probability array to increasing sums as follows:

```
System.out.println("Before: " + Arrays.toString(probabilities));
Arrays.parallelPrefix(probabilities, (a,b)->a + b);       
System.out.println("After:  " + Arrays.toString(probabilities));
```

prints

```
Before: [0.2, 0.75, 0.05]
After:  [0.2, 0.95, 1.0]
```

Comment: short and simple. thanks